# Windows Explorer Alternate Data Stream Shell Extension

Tags: windows, winapi, shell-extensions, alternate-data-stream

I have some files that use alternate data stream and are not shown on windows explorer. I would like to make a shell extension or a program that runs on background that when I use windows explorer and navigates to a folders that has alternate data streams files, to show this file to windows explorer but with an overlay icon on it.

Is this possible? Is there a sample code to check?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok but how show alternate data stream files on the windows explorer?

Comment: Again, it seems unlikely to me that the shell would admit adding extra virtual items to a directory. Now, it would certainly be possible for a virtual namespace, but I doubt it for a true directory.

Comment: David, overlay icons are possible. They don't want to add actual items to a directory.

Comment: You may want to rethink, given the tags in your question. You would inject Java or the .NET runtime *into every process that uses a common file dialog*. While abysmal from a performance perspective there is also the greater problem that this causes incompatibilities with applications targeting a different framework version. Do it in C++, please.

Comment: Even on C++ how do this? Is there examples or something to work on this?

Comment: @Joey OK, I thought the Q was about representing the streams as items in the file view. I guess I'm wrong there.

Comment: Hm, the comment on the now-deleted answer suggests otherwise, though.

Comment: I thought one of Microsoft's examples on shell extensions was exactly what the OP is asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a shell property sheet handler available from Microsoft called [StrmExt](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/6/fc6943eb-790a-44aa-b32d-14ed7e22fd5d/ntfsext.exe). Granted, it's not quite what you're looking for, was written for Windows 2000 and Windows XP, and [has to be recompiled for 64 bit versions of Explorer](http://www.boredomsoft.org/strmext.dll-on-x64-windows.bs), but it includes the C++ source code, which should give you a place to start, at least.

In Windows Vista, two new API functions were introduced to allow easier enumeration of Alternate Data Streams: [FindFirstStreamW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextStreamW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These functions work much like the other `FindFirstX` and `FindNextX` type functions that have been in Win32 for years.

Answer (score 3):

Another, more recent, option, that works with Windows Explorer x64, too, is AlternateStreamExtension. It also provides icon overlays.

You can find it [here](http://www.benf.org/other/alternatestreamoverlay/).

Comment: Doesn't work with Windows 10, though, unfortunately. I get a DLL error when attempting to view a stream set via PowerShell.

Comment: @seagull: I tried it just now with Windows 10 x64: Works like a charm for me. Maybe you mixed 32 and 64bit DLLs?

Comment: No, I installed the right DLL. I can view some information but the second I try and view the information as hex, for example, it crashes.